# Select total count by joining two tables but getting an empty count response when filtering query

Tags: count

Currently I have two tables where I want to join them and retrieve the total count based on the food_type. One table is called `Food_Categories` while the other table is called `Food consumption`. I am trying to join the Food Categories table and the Food Consumption table with Food_Type Filter = "Option1" or "Option2" or "Option3".

Below is my query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Food_Consumption
inner join Food_Categories ON Food_Consumption.food_id = Food_Categories.food_id
WHERE food_type = 'Option1' || 'Option2' || 'Option3'
```

When I queried that I got a total count of 0. However I am supposed to retrieve a total count of at least 176. Am I joining the two tables correctly while grouping the id and filtering Option1,2, and 3. They have one thing in common, which is food expiration date: 1/1/2009 (which I group them with with WHERE) I read on other documentation that if we want to compare the two tables we use inner join group_by but I am getting different total count than what I am expected to? In addition What happens on joining with 3 tables? Does it also encounter inner join with 3 tables same way?

Comment: Check if both the tables have food_category_id. If yes then use it in the join condition. Also, Please share the schema of both tables.

Comment: Tag only the RDBMS you are actually using. It makes no sense to have two for this question. And start by explaining the objective. The failed implementation is not that useful on its own. Plus table definitions, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an issue with the `WHERE` clause. you used || to filter food_type, this operator could be used for concatenation in this context, try to use IN with multiple values.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Food_Consumption 
inner join Food_Categories ON Food_Consumption.food_id = Food_Categories.food_id 
WHERE food_type IN (‘Option1’, ‘Option2’, ‘Option3’) AND food_expiration_date = ‘1/1/2009’
```

When joining 3 tables, you could use the same syntax adding another join statement for the 3rd table.